# Best solution to transfer private key over two web domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptography, rsa, websecurity

What is the best way to pass the private key to one website to another one. Website A will have a link with encrypted URL. On click of the link it will go to Website B where the encrypted text requires decrypt. Encryption is done throuh RSA. 
I can see two approach can be here. 
Create one time private key and share with decryption domains. Here no need to pass the key with every request.
Another is two create key with every request. In this case how can I pass the key securely to other domain. 
Which approach is the best or anything else I should do with respect to security.
Or any other best solution.

Comment: Might be suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What protocol do you use to transfer the private key? Can you use the simple https tunnel to pass the sensitive info without having it explicitly encrypted and decrypted by your websites?

Comment: I have personally not encountered any use cases where I've needed to transfer a private key over a network.  I suspect you have alternatives to doing that.  Are you aware that public key cryptography is designed specifically so that private keys do *not* need to be transferred over a network?  You may get a better answer if you describe the whole problem you are trying to solve, instead of framing it as "I need to transfer a private key over a network".

If I was reviewing an architecture where private keys were sent over a network, that would be a big red flag for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use public key cryptography to securely send data (in your case a private key) from one side to another. While both sides have access to the public key, only one side has access to the private key. While the public key is used to encrypt data the private key is used to decrypt the data. The size of data which can be encrypted this way is limited (usually only 128-256 bytes). Therefore normally this technique is used to encrypt/decrypt another encrypted key (AES...) which encrypts/decrypts the actual data.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // your data you want to securely send from B to A without revealing the content
        byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        // side A
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider full_rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

        byte[] publickey = full_rsa.ExportCspBlob(false);

        // send the public key to B
        // send(publickey)...

        // side B
        //send encrypted data back to side A
        byte[] encrypteddata = EncryptData(publickey, data); 

        // side A
        // decrypt the data encryped by side B
        byte[] decrypteddata = DecryptData(full_rsa, encrypteddata); 

        // decrypteddata = 1,2,3,4,5,6
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptData(System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider full_rsa, byte[] data)
    {
        System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(new System.IO.MemoryStream(data));
        int encryptedkeylength = br.ReadInt32();
        int aeskeylength = br.ReadInt32();
        int aesivlength = br.ReadInt32();
        byte[] encryptedaeskey = br.ReadBytes(encryptedkeylength);
        byte[] encrypteddata = br.ReadBytes( (int)(data.Length - br.BaseStream.Position));
        br.Close();

        byte[] decryptedkey = full_rsa.Decrypt(encryptedaeskey, false);

        br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(new System.IO.MemoryStream(decryptedkey));
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.Aes myAes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create())
        {
            byte[] aeskey = br.ReadBytes(aeskeylength);
            byte[] aesiv = br.ReadBytes(aesivlength);
            System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform decryptor = myAes.CreateDecryptor(aeskey, aesiv);

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream msDecrypt = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream csEncrypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        bw.Write(encrypteddata);
                    }
                    return msDecrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] publickey, byte[] data)
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.Aes myAes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create())
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor(myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            using (System.IO.MemoryStream msEncrypt = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream csEncrypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    System.IO.MemoryStream headerms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    System.IO.BinaryWriter headerbw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(headerms);

                    using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider public_key = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
                        public_key.ImportCspBlob(publickey);

                        byte[] encryptedkey = public_key.Encrypt(Combine(myAes.Key, myAes.IV), false);
                        headerbw.Write(encryptedkey.Length);
                        headerbw.Write(myAes.Key.Length);
                        headerbw.Write(myAes.IV.Length);
                        headerbw.Write(encryptedkey);
                        headerbw.Flush();
                        bw.Write(data);
                    }                            

                    byte[] result = Combine(headerms.ToArray(), msEncrypt.ToArray());
                    headerbw.Close();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
        byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
        return ret;
    }
}
```